# How can I set limits and track a player in a text based game?

Tags: python, loops, oop, if-statement

For a final project I need to create a text based game where the user has control over the player and can move in any direction they want. I cannot think of a way to make the program follow the position of the player and return it constantly so they know where they are, and how to set a limit to the size of the room they are in.
We barely learned about OOP and GUI so they are not required to be in the project but any insight would be greatly appreciated.

```
 #list of directions they are able to move
    actions = [['W = North','A = West','S = South','D = East']]

    #Print out actions as a table
    for row in actions:
        print("\t".join(row))

    #Input on which direction the user would like to move
    walk = input('Please enter which direction you would like to go')

    #if statement ouputting decision or looping for a correct input
    if walk.upper() == 'W':
        print('You walk North a few steps.')
    elif walk.upper() == 'A':
        print('You walk West a few steps.')
    elif walk.upper() == 'S':
        print('You walk South a few steps.')
    elif walk.upper() == 'D':
        print('You walk East a few steps')
    else:
        print('Please choose a correct action')
```

I currently have this for the movements they can take, but I do not understand how to incorporate a limit to them. I was thinking something like
`if walk.upper() == 'W' >= 4: print('You cannot go any further in this direction')`
But I do not know if this will work or how to make it work

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can create a list object that records the player's current location and update it each time the player makes a move. I'm guessing that the code snippet you provided is inside some kind of loop, so before that loop, you could initialize it.

```
current_location = [0,0]
```

After each input, you would increment x-y coordinates as appropriate (and assign it to a different list) and then check if the new location violates those rules. If the new location passes the check, assign the current_location list the value of the new location and loop again.

I don't want to give you the entire answer, but here is what I might change the walk north bit to if the only rule was that the user could not walk farther north than ordinate 2.

```
if walk.upper() == 'W':
    new_location = current_location
    new_location[1] += 1
    if new_location[1] > 2:
        print("You bump into a wall")
    else:
        current_location = new_location
        print('You walk North a few steps.')
```

Remember that Python lists are zero-indexed.

Answer (score 0):

Define a function receives the input and current position of the player. The function then defines a temporary variable and makes changes to it. The function then sees if the player is trying to get out of bounds. If yes, then have the original position unchanged. If no, then reflect the changes to the original position variable. Then return the position variable for the next use.

Then use  a `while` loop to get input continuously and overwrite the global position variable with the return value of the function.

Sample code:

```py
def control(inp, pos):
    if inp.upper() == 'W':
        temp = pos[:]
        temp[1] += 1
        if temp[1] < 4:
            print('You walk North one step.')
            pos[1] = temp[1]
        else:
            print('You cannot go any further in this direction')
    elif inp.upper() == 'A':
        temp = pos[:]
        temp[0] -= 1
        if temp[0] > -4:
            print('You walk West one step.')
            pos[0] = temp[0]
        else:
            print('You cannot go any further in this direction')
    elif inp.upper() == 'S':
        temp = pos[:]
        temp[1] -= 1
        if temp[1] > -4:
            print('You walk South one step.')
            pos[1] = temp[1]
        else:
            print('You cannot go any further in this direction')
    elif inp.upper() == 'D':
        temp = pos[:]
        temp[0] += 1
        if temp[0] < 4:
            print('You walk East one step.')
            pos[0] = temp[0]
        else:
            print('You cannot go any further in this direction')
    else:
        print('Please choose a correct action')
    # print(pos)  add this line if you want to monitor the position variable.
    return pos

walk = input('Please enter which direction you would like to go: ')
playerPos = control(walk, [0, 0])

while 1:
    walk = input('Please enter which direction you would like to go: ')
    playerPos = control(walk, playerPos)
```

And by the way, don't know why you have used double square brackets for defining `actions` list.